# iPhone locked in portrait mode

Tags: iphone

My question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3691965/iphone-locked-portrait-ipad-locked-landscape) thread

which says to lock the iPhone in portrait mode and doesnot allow it to go to landscape mode.

This can be done easily but my concern is I want to lock all the applications running to the portrait mode in iOS 4.

That is if I have locked the orientation mode and has minimised my application then the none of the application in iPhone shall go to landscape mode.

So my question is

1. Is it possible
2. if yes then how? Any ideas or link will be really appreciated.

Edit: I know this is already available in iOs 4.0 but its hard to find also this is just for information purpose.
For those who disagree: check out the [link](http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/orientationlock/id384597941?mt=8)

Thanks in advance...

Edit: **Finally as per everyones suggestion I think it is not at all possible to lock other applications orientation through our application.**

Comment: iOS 4 already has this functionality built-in, no need to create an app for it: http://i.imgur.com/ScUtI.png (sent from my iPhone)

Comment: I would be really disgusted if I found out that a 3rd party app would change the behavior of other apps or the device itself!

Comment: Please checkout the link on appstore already doing this http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/orientationlock/id384597941?mt=8

Comment: The link you provided does not lock the orientation of other applications. It just has its own browser and music app that it locks the orientation of.

Comment: Seriously? There's a $0.99 app to do what iOS 4 already does?!

Comment: I want to delete the question but not sure.. Why is it not allowing me to delete the question :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How would you feel if any 3rd application is accesing the orientation of your application and that of device.

So Its all handled out by Apple itself. Also as told no application is allowed to effect the system variable..

So in case you succeed in finding out the hack for this thing... Then also your application is gonna rejected by apple...

Still all the best for ur research :P

Comment: thanks for the answer but I think you havent read the last line of my question which says `Finally as per everyones suggestion I think it is not at all possible to lock other applications orientation through our application.`

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but you can't lock the orientation via public APIs, and if you are going to use private APIs, Apple will never approve your app.

Comment: Please checkout the link on appstore already doing this http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/orientationlock/id384597941?mt=8

Answer (score 1):

An iPhone app cant affect system wide variables such as screen lock. If you could, then there would be nothing keeping you from accessing all the other data on the device as well. Sorry, but if you want your app approved by Apple, you'll have to give up on this feature.

Comment: Please checkout the link on appstore already doing this http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/orientationlock/id384597941?mt=8

Comment: The link you provided does not lock the orientation of other applications. It just has its own browser and music app that it locks the orientation of.